# in_array() - Array in Array Search doesnt work

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to do something like this:

```
$fetch = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
$input = array('a', 'c', 'e');

    if (in_array($input, $fetch)) {
        echo "Array Values Exists";
    }

    else {
        echo 'Invalid Values Exists';
    }
```

Basically, I am trying to see if the values in `$input` array exists in the `$fetch` array. But the above results always shows as `Invalid Values Exists` instead of showing `Array Values Exists`. When I read the `in_array()` documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), from example #3, I thought I can use array in array for the parameters. Have I understood this wrong? What is the right way to do this?

Comment: surely [array_intersect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) or [array_diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) are the best functions for this test rather than looping through the values

Comment: excellent. I wasnt aware of those. `array_intersect()` will work perfect for me since I am actually using this to match and validate the checkbox values from `$_POST` and `array_intersect()` will actually work well to filter out the array values instead of using a foreach statement that will be a few more lines of codes. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
$fetch = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
$input = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$flag = true;
foreach($input as $key=>$val){
    if (!in_array($val, $fetch)) {
        $flag = false;
        break;
    }
}

if($flag=== true)
    echo "Values in input exists in fetch";
else
    echo "Values in input does not exists in fetch";
```

Comment: I tested this code and it works perfect! This will be really very useful! My other option was using `array_intersect()` like Mark Baker suggested above to filter out the values. But your code actually checks each value and returns false even if 1 of them doesnt match. That is excellent. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 2):

`$needle` can be an array, but that means you're looking for *the array*, not *the elements in the array*.

```
$a = array(array('p', 'h'), array('p', 'r'), 'o');

if (in_array(array('p', 'h'), $a)) {
//Note that array('p', 'h') is in the $haystack array, but not 'p' or 'h' alone.
    echo "'ph' was found\n";
}
```

If you want to check for the elements of the array, you'll need to iterate it somehow (be it with `foreach` or `array_map()`).

Comment: aha.. now I understand. I thought it was checking the values in the array and matching it. Re-reading the documentation after your posts made sense that its actually matching the array itself and not its values. Thanks for explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use $input as array.

See below example :

```
<?php
$a = array(array('p', 'h'), array('p', 'r'), 'o');

if (in_array(array('p', 'h'), $a)) {
 echo "'ph' was found\n";
}

if (in_array(array('f', 'i'), $a)) {
  echo "'fi' was found\n";
}

if (in_array('o', $a)) {
  echo "'o' was found\n";
}
```

?>

The above example will output:

'ph' was found
   'o' was found